# Selecting by specific elements in a list in HQL

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I'm implementing a "QueryEngine" design pattern for dynamic queries
on with loose connection to a Query Language (Like LINQ).
I am having a hard time writing the HQL for a specific elemt from a list.
i.e:

```
public class Cat()
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Cat Child { get; set; }
}
```

Now I'm trying to select a cat by his child, so the HQL should be something like this:

```
SELECT cat FROM CAT as cat  
WHERE cat.Child = {"Any value or subsearch"}
```

But if I alter the Cat class to have a one-to-many reference:

```
public class Cat()
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Cat> Children { get; set; }
}
```

The HQL will now look like this (I'm trying to select by a specific child in the list)

```
SELECT cat FROM CAT as cat  
WHERE {"Any value or subsearch"} IN elements(Children}
```

My question is, Can I make the second query to be similiar in the order to the first one
Something like this:

```
SELECT cat FROM CAT as cat  
WHERE Children CONTAIN {"Any value or subsearch"}
```

Thanks [=

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for something like this:

```
select cat from Cat cat
    join cat.Children child
    where child.Something is true
```

Comment: The problem wit this HQL is that i'll have to tell the QueryEngine to insert a "Join" clause after the select.. The design pattern is divided into different classes and each class is responsible for inserting part of the HQL into the overall query.. So the generator of the SELECT clause won't even know about the generator of the WHERE clause..

Answer (score 1):

Neither HQL nor Linq are great for dynamically constructed queries.

I suggest you use [Criteria](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria) instead.